# Keep the legend and y-axis in a specific order with ggplot

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

Let's consider the following data

```
analysisdata$question = c("Q1","Q1","Q1","Q2","Q2","Q2","Q3","Q3","Q3","Q4","Q4","Q4")
analysisdata$name = c("G1","G2","G3","G1","G2","G3","G1","G2","G3","G1","G2","G3")
analysisdata$pointEstimate = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
analysisdata$ci.max = c(2,3,4,2,3,4,2,3,4,2,3,4)
analysisdata$ci.min = c(0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2)
```

And the following plotting function:

```
plotCI <- function(data, ymin = 0, ymax = 1.0, xlab = "XLAB", ylab = "YLAB"){
  pd = position_dodge(.6)    ### How much to jitter the points on the plot
  g <- ggplot(data,                ### The data frame to use. 
              aes(x     = factor(y_axis_items),
                  y     = measure,
                  color = factor(legend_factor))) +
    
    geom_point(size  = 2, position = pd) +
    
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin  = upperBound_CI,
                      ymax  = lowerBound_CI),
                  width = 0.2, 
                  size  = 0.7, 
                  position = pd) +
    coord_flip() +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(ymin,ymax)) +
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white', colour = 'white'),axis.title=element_text(size = rel(1.2), colour = "black"),axis.text=element_text(size = rel(1.2), colour = "black"),panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "#DDDDDD"),panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank())+ theme(axis.title = element_text(face = "bold")) +
    xlab(xlab)+
    ylab(ylab);
  
  print(g)
}
```

If I call this code

```
dataToPrint <- data.frame(factor(analysisdata$name),factor(analysisdata$question),analysisdata$pointEstimate, analysisdata$ci.max, analysisdata$ci.min)
colnames(dataToPrint) <- c("legend_factor", "y_axis_items","measure", "lowerBound_CI", "upperBound_CI")
plotCI(dataToPrint, xlab="Questions", ylab="", ymax=5)
```

It gives me the following graph:

[image: Image 1]

However, what I would like to do here is to try and get the ordering on the y-axis sorted out different, say, G1 at the top, then G2, G3, G4 (but for the sake of having something reusable by more, let's imagine that the solution to just reverse the alphabetical order is not ok and that I want a custom order). I would also like to be able to order the legend in the order that it appears on the graph (so G3 at the top here).

I have tried to add the following to my plotting function `scale_x_discrete(limits=data$y_axis_item) +` but this produces the wrong kind of graph in the end and does not solve my problem.
[image: Image 2]

Would anyone have a solution to that. I have found questions on here which used factors to preserve the specific order in the data frame, but that does not work when there are duplicated IDs as in my data frame here:

[image: Image 3]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reverse the order you could make use of `forcats::fct_rev`. To reverse the order of the legend you could make use of `guides(color = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))`. And if you want a custom order for the y-axis this could be achieved via e.g. `factor(dataToPrint$y_axis_items, levels = c("Q2", "Q3", "Q1", "Q4"))`

```r
library(ggplot2)

colnames(dataToPrint) <- c("y_axis_items", "legend_factor", "measure", "lowerBound_CI", "upperBound_CI")

# Reverse
dataToPrint$y_axis_items <- forcats::fct_rev(dataToPrint$y_axis_items)

plotCI(dataToPrint, xlab = "Questions", ylab = "", ymax = 5) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))
```

[image]

Set a custom order

```r
dataToPrint$y_axis_items <- factor(dataToPrint$y_axis_items, levels = c("Q2", "Q3", "Q1", "Q4"))

plotCI(dataToPrint, xlab = "Questions", ylab = "", ymax = 5) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))
```

[image]

**Plotting function**

```
plotCI <- function(data, ymin = 0, ymax = 1.0, xlab = "XLAB", ylab = "YLAB") {
  pd <- position_dodge(.6) ### How much to jitter the points on the plot
  g <- ggplot(
    data, ### The data frame to use.
    aes(
      x = y_axis_items,
      y = measure,
      color = legend_factor
    )
  ) +
    geom_point(size = 2, position = pd) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(
      ymin = upperBound_CI,
      ymax = lowerBound_CI
    ),
    width = 0.2,
    size = 0.7,
    position = pd
    ) +
    coord_flip() +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(ymin, ymax)) +
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "white"), 
          axis.title = element_text(size = rel(1.2), colour = "black"), 
          axis.text = element_text(size = rel(1.2), colour = "black"), 
          panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "#DDDDDD"), 
          panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank()) +
    theme(axis.title = element_text(face = "bold")) +
    xlab(xlab) +
    ylab(ylab)

  g
}
```

**DATA**

```
dataToPrint <- data.frame(
  question = c("Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q3", "Q3", "Q3", "Q4", "Q4", "Q4"),
  name = c("G1", "G2", "G3", "G1", "G2", "G3", "G1", "G2", "G3", "G1", "G2", "G3"),
  pointEstimate = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
  ci.max = c(2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4),
  ci.min = c(0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the very complete answer. How would you make sure that you can give a customised order for the legend too? Not just the reverse. Will accept as the answer after that. Already upvoted though.

Comment: Same approach as for the axis items e.g. `dataToPrint$legend_factor <- factor(dataToPrint$legend_factor, levels = c("G2", "G3", "G1"))`. Reversing via `guide_legend` makes sure that the legend items appear in the same order as the error bars in the plot.

Comment: "Reversing via guide_legend makes sure that the legend items appear in the same order as the error bars in the plot." Does it always do that?

Comment: Also, is there a way to always integrate this in my plotting function @stefan ? So I don't have to always think of doing this?

Comment: Hm. In general it depends on the kind of plot as `reverse=TRUE` just reverses the order of the legend items. And sure could you add the code line `+ guides(...)` to your plotting function.

Comment: Thanks! This is amazing! Thanks again for a very complete and thorough answer!